# c# combobox has a datasource, how do i make it display a specific element?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have a datatable as the source of a combobox:

```
1
3
2
4
5
```

without knowing the order of the elemnts inside the datatable, and only knowing the exact text, is it possible to display a specific element like '`4`' ?

Comment: can you explain? do you want to show a query result in your combo box?

Comment: no i just want a specific element displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you should do this:

```
comboBox1.Text = "4";
```

or change the value of related field in DataTable:

```
((MyDataRowType)((DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current).Row).myFieldName = "4";
```

Comment: so try setting the value for the related field in your `DataTable`

Comment: doesn't this just change the currently selected value to "4", instead of finding "4" in the data source and selecting that item?

Comment: @adrift: maybe there are other fields in that data source... so if u try finding an element, you are changing everything...

Answer (score 1):

In DataBound event of your dropdownlist try this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.Items[i].Text == "4")
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = i;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myComboBox.SelectedItem = "4";
```

Comment: i cannot do this, it is attached to a datasource, there's no selectedvalue property