# c# loop through combobox where datasource is a datatable with text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to run through every item in a combobox using a `foreach` loop? How would I do it?

The thing is I have a `System.Data.DataRowView` there because the combobox is attached to a `DataTable`. How do I convert from that to `string`?

Comment: are you doing this to look for a specific value in the combobox?  related to your last question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, it looks like this:

```
foreach(object item in myComboBox.Items)
{
   DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;

   if(row != null)
   {
        string displayValue = row["myColumnName"].ToString();

        // do something
   }
   else
       // error: item was not of type DataRowView
}
```

also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx

Comment: item.ToString() will give you the value that is displayed in the combo box for that specific item.

Comment: @i am a girl, if you are looking for an item with specific text, there is a method for that.

Comment: @adrift thank u very much, the thing is i have 'System.Data.DataRowView' there because the combobox is attached to datatable, how do i convert frmo that to string

Comment: if your 'item' is of type DataRowView, you can type cast it:  DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;    and then you could get a specific column's value like this:   row["columnName"].

Comment: @remus great can u put this in your answer please

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var item in combobox1.Items)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

If you know the content is a string, you can do

```
foreach (object item in combobox1.Items)
{
     string text = (item as string);
     //do stuff with the text
}
```

If you are using .net 3.5 or later, you can shorten it a bit by using the `Cast<T>()` Extension method of `IEnumerable<T>` (which is implemented by `ObjectCollection`, the type of `ComboBox.Items`):

```
foreach (string text in combobox1.Items.Cast<string>())
{
     //do stuff with the text
}
```

Comment: thank u  very much, the thing is i have 'System.Data.DataRowView'  there because the combobox is attached to datatable, how do i convert frmo that to string

Comment: You would need to know the specific index of the data that is displayed in the combobox and call item[index]. Sorry, I can't help you more because I have no experience concerning Databinding in WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128771/c-combobox-has-a-datasource-how-do-i-make-it-display-a-specific-element), it sounds like you want to loop through the items to find a matching text value.  Instead, you can use the [ComboBox.FindStringExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c440x2eb.aspx) method to do a case-insensitive search, which will return the index of the first match it finds, or -1 if it doesn't find the text in question:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact("4");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is just a standard collection. Eg:

```
foreach(object item in myComboBox.Items)
```

"object" is probably (but not necessarily) a string. If you know it is always a string, you could change it to:

```
foreach(string item in myComboBox.Items)
```

Comment: the second code won't work, as myCombobox.Items is a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

yes - iterate through the items collection of the control:

```
foreach(var item in this.myCombobox.Items) 
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: it's essentially the item.ToString() value

Comment: thank u very much, the thing is i have 'System.Data.DataRowView' there because the combobox is attached to datatable, how do i convert frmo that to string

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(ListItem item in this.myCombobox.Items) 
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( object item in ComboBoxName.Items )
{
    <dosomething>
}
```

What else can I say?  This accesses them in order, but all will be objects.  It's up to you to determine the item's type.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for ages with this issue, as I often use ComboBox controls, binded to a List<>s  of various different classes.

I didn't really want to hardcode field names in my function, or have a separate SelectItemByValue function for each type of List<> class I'd be using.

I eventually came up with the following reusable solution.

```
List<EmployeeRecord> m_listOfEmployees = GetListOfEmployees();
...
comboBoxEmployees.DataSource = m_listOfEmployees;
comboBoxEmployees.DisplayMember = "EmployeeName";
comboBoxEmployees.ValueMember = "EmployeeID";
```

To select the ComboBox item with a particular Employee ID:

```
   int someEmployeeID = 4;
   ComboBoxHelper.SetComboBoxSelectionByValue<EmployeeRecord>(comboBoxEmployees, someEmployeeID);
```

And here's the function which does the work.

Brace yourself, it's not pretty.

```
public static void SetComboBoxSelectionByValue<T>(ComboBox ctrl, int? value)
{
    //  If the ComboBox has no items, disable it  (so the user can immediately see there's nothing selectable)
    ctrl.Enabled = (ctrl.Items.Count > 0);

    int inx = 0;
    foreach (T t in ctrl.Items)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (info.Name == ctrl.ValueMember)
            {
                object val = info.GetValue(t, null);
                if (val.ToString() == value.Value.ToString())
                {
                    ctrl.SelectedIndex = inx;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        inx++;
    }

    if (ctrl.Items.Count > 0)
        ctrl.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Notice how you have to call the function, passing it the **type** of objects that are being stored in each ComboBoxItem (**EmployeeRecord**, in this example), along with a pointer to your ComboBox and the Value of the item you want to set as the SelectedItem.

```
ComboBoxHelper.SetComboBoxSelectionByValue<EmployeeRecord>(comboBoxEmployees, someEmployeeID);
```

The function steps through the Items in the ComboBox, finds the "ValueMember" field in that item's record  (EmployeeID, in this example) and compares the ValueMember's value with the desired *value* parameter.

I know, I know, it's not pretty, but when you bind a List to a ComboBox, then you can't use DataRowView:

```
DataRowView row = item as DataRowView;
string displayValue = row["someColumnName"].ToString();
```

And if you want one generic SetComboBoxSelectionByValue function, which will work with Lists of any type of classes, then you need to start getting into PropertyInfos, to find the value of a field in your particular class.