# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I've comboBox in windows forms which I've bound to datasource, which is correctly returning Id associated with particular name in combobox whenever form loads.

```
private void PurchaseMaster_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = productMasterBAL.GetTable("Select * from productMaster");
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
    combBox1.ValueMember = "ProductId";
}
```

But whenever I select any value in Combobox I get:

**NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object reference not set to an
     instance of an object**

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

           DataRowView row = comboBox1.SelectedValue as DataRowView;
           MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", row["ProductId"])); //This line is causing exception
}
```

Could anyone please tell how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `PName.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: it was actually 'combobox1'

Comment: @Dusk Check out my post and try to use the properties available , this should get you the desired values

Comment: As an aside, set your DisplayMember and ValueMember properties before setting DataSource - each time you change Display/Value member, the data source is re-bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking for the values like this

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
   MessageBox.Show(cmb.SelectedValue.ToString());// cmb.SelectedText
}
```

This should give you the selected Product Id in the combobox

The items in Combobox are stored as [`ObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.aspx) and not exactly a DataRow or DataRowView as you seem to be expecting.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be checking combobox1.SelectedItem rather than SelectedValue.

```
 DataRowView row = combobox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
```

SelectedItem is the databound row which created that entry in the combobox. SelectedValue will be the ProductID of that row.

Or, you could try

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string productId = combobox1.SelectedValue as string;
    if (productId != null) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(productId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you debugged? Check that row isn't null? from msdn:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

Have you checked if this expression is valid as type?

Answer (score 0):

May be `row["ProductId"]` is not a string field I think, so its returning an exception while formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast `PName.SelectedValue` which is of type "String" to object DataRowView\ using 'safe-cast'. `as` returns null if object can't be cast to desired class. So, the actual mistake is in

```
 DataRowView row = PName.SelectedValue as DataRowView;
```

Try direct cast with `DataRowView row = (DataRowView)PName.SelectedValue`, you'll definitely will get an error.

You should query your data source again to fetch data object.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my generic solution on this thread:

[c# loop through combobox where datasource is a datatable with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128886/c-sharp-loop-through-combobox-where-datasource-is-a-datatable-with-text/15085837#15085837)

Basically, you can call my function, telling it the type of each ComboBox Item, and it'll do the rest.

```
ComboBoxHelper.SetComboBoxSelectionByValue<EmployeeRecord>(comboBoxEmployees, someEmployeeID);
```

Hope this helps!